# I created an email form validation function that displays an alert message but am not satisfied

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created the function to display the alert message on keypress then if the user does not include "@" in the field, it should keep showing but once "@" is added then the alert message should disappear.

Here is the code:

```js
function makeHappen() {
    var take = document.getElementById('emailID');
    var a = document.getElementById("alert3second");
    if (!take.value.indexOf("@") > -1) {
        a.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        a.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control font-weight-bold" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" id="emailID" onclick="formValidator2()" name="budget3" onkeypress="makeHappen()" required>

<div id="alert3" class="alert-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-warning pr-2 pt-1"></i>
    Please Your email address is required
</div>

<div id="alert3second" class="alert-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-warning pr-2 pt-1"></i>
    Enter a valid email
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try  `if (! (take.value.indexOf("@") > -1) ) {`

Comment: You're inverting the indexOf result, not the test against `-1`. Just remove the `!` and swap `"block"` and `"none"`. You can also consider testing the address against a suitable [regular expression](https://emailregex.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `onkeypress` use `onkeyup`

> The onkeyup attribute fires when the user releases a key (on the
> keyboard).
> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeyup.asp

and add `style="display:none;"` to `alert3second` div to make the message disappears when there is no value in the input

```js
    
function makeHappen() {
    var take = document.getElementById('emailID');
    var a = document.getElementById("alert3second");
    
    if (take.value.indexOf("@") == -1) {
 
        a.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        a.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="email" class="form-control font-weight-bold"
    placeholder="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" 
    id="emailID" onclick="formValidator2()"
    name="budget3" onkeyup="makeHappen()" required>
    
    <div id="alert3" class="alert-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-warning pr-2 pt-1"></i>
      Please Your email address is required
    </div>
    
    <div id="alert3second" class="alert-danger" style="display:none;">
      <i class="fa fa-warning pr-2 pt-1"></i>
      Enter a valid email
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your if statement needs to be made clearer:

```
if (take.value.indexOf('@') == -1)
```

You can test this by running your current if statement like so:

```
> !"hello".indexOf("@") > -1 
true
> !"hello@".indexOf("@") > -1 
true
```

I would probably point out that you should name your variables a bit better. Maybe instead of 'take' you should call it emailID?

```
function validateEmail() {
    var emailId = document.getElementById('emailID').value;
    var errorMsg = document.getElementById('alert3second');
    if (emailId.indexOf('@') == -1) {
        errorMsg.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        errorMsg.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that clearer than `take.value.indexOf("@") == -1`?

Comment: AKX I think that's the way I understand it best

Comment: @AKX I've tried your solution but it didn't work. Can you explain it to me better please